# ASP controls need Double-Click to get focus due to OnTextChanged Event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got a situation here.

I have around 5 ASP controls in my page including some Text-Box and Radio Buttons. These controls are the part of a form where the user will fill data one by one into these controls. Now, the problem is each of these controls have `AutoPostBack = True` and `OnTextChanged` or `OnCheckedChanged` event associated with it.

Here comes the problem. Whenever the user fills one of these controls and try to navigate to the next control, that control needs Double-Click to get focus. It is very inconvenient to double click every control while filling up the form.

I tried to come over the situation by setting `Page.SetFocus(<control>);` in every `OnTextChanged` event to the next control in the form. But the same doesn't work in case of a Radio Button. It also doesn't work when the sequence of focus is changed.

I need a work-around to overcome the problem. I can't remove the `OnTextChanged` or `OnCheckedChanged` events due to the requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's actually happening is the page is being posted back and then focus is shifting back to the control that caused the postback. A double click isn't actually strictly happening. The first click causes the first control to lose focus, thus causing the postback. The second click then focuses the control you want after the postback has occurred.

What you can do is capture the control that has received focus prior to the postback and when the page reloads set focus back to that control.

Here's an example (**Updated**):

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True"
            onFocus="SetNextControl(this);"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged"
            AutoPostBack="True" GroupName="RBGroup" onClick="SetNextControl(this);" />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" AutoPostBack="True" GroupName="RBGroup" runat="server" onClick="SetNextControl(this);"/>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox2_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True"
            onFocus="SetNextControl(this);"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            if (document.getElementById("<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>").value != "") {
                 var controlToFocus = document.getElementById(document.getElementById("<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>").value);
                 controlToFocus.focus();
                 document.getElementById("<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>").value = "";
             }
        })

         function SetNextControl(e) {
             document.getElementById("<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>").value = e.id;

         }         
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

The above sample isn't perfect, I'm not sure if it'll work the way you want with RadioButtons as there is no onFocus event for them. I've changed them to use onClick so that at least focus remains on the last selected radio button. Hopefully this at least get's you a little bit closer to what you want.

Comment: My controls are in Content Page. How will I call `onload = "onLoad();"` in the master page?? Please help.

Comment: I am repeatedly getting the following error in the first line of onLoad function.

`Error: Unable to get value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined`

Comment: @ChandanRoy updated my answer, now works within a master page, pay attention to my comments about the radio buttons.

Comment: Can you tell me whether I can write two `$(document).ready(function() {});` on the same page?

Comment: No I don't think that's possible, only one would logically execute. Just include the necessary code in one function.

Comment: The code just worked fine with textboxes. But the radiobuttons still need double-click. I'm working on that.

Comment: I was not able to make this work over Radio Buttons. But for textbox, it's working perfectly.